# Convert a list of ints to a float

Tags: python, floating-point-conversion

I am trying to convert a number stored as a list of ints to a float type. I got the number via a serial console and want to reassemble it back together into a float.
The way I would do it in C is something like this:

```
bit_data = ((int16_t)byte_array[0] << 8) | byte_array[1];
result = (float)bit_data;
```

What I tried to use in python is a much more simple conversion:

```
result = int_list[0]*256.0 + int_list[1]
```

However, this does not preserve the sign of the result, as the C code does.
What is the right way to do this in python?

**UPDATE:**
Python version is 2.7.3.
My byte array has a length of 2.
in the python code byte_array is list of ints. I've renamed it to avoid misunderstanding. I can not just use the float() function because it will not preserve the sign of the number.

Comment: How big is your byte_array? Is it is 4 elements? Your code doesn't make that clear...

Comment: Also, you didn't mention which python version...

Comment: What is the a byte_array? Is a list of ints, a bytes object?

Comment: Is it too slow to unpack your byte array into a native Python int? Because once you've got it as a native int, float(int) is usually good enough.

Comment: As far as i know, python supports the "<<" operator while maintaining the sign, can you try it?

Comment: updated the post to answer the first questions

Comment: By "list of ints" are the ints supposed to represent bytes in a larger multi-byte signed integer? If so, convert `int_list[0]` to a signed byte (if > 127, its -(int_list[0]-127).

Comment: Ah, if float() isn't preserving number signs there's probably shenanigans where your byte stream is turned into that int array. +1 the answers recommending to use the `struct` module.

Comment: Do I understand this right. You have two bytes. Those bytes represent a 16-bit int, which you want to extract and then cast as a float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by what data you have, and how it is represented in Python. As I understand it, you have received two unsigned bytes over a serial connection, which are now represented by a list of two python ints. This data represents a big endian 16-bit signed integer, which you want to extract and turn into a float. eg. `[0xFF, 0xFE]` -> `-2` -> `-2.0`

```
import array, struct

two_unsigned_bytes = [255, 254] # represented by ints
byte_array = array.array("B", two_unsigned_bytes) 
# change above to "b" if the ints represent signed bytes ie. in range -128 to 127
signed_16_bit_int, = struct.unpack(">h", byte_array)
float_result = float(signed_16_bit_int)
```

Comment: I hadn't considered converting to a byte array... very cool. I think its big endian... so ">h". An example other than `[255, 255]` makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks! This one suits me the most!

Comment: @tdelaney Good call, about the endianness. I was hung up about the sign of the data, and was trying to think of a byte pattern whose value was different, but obvious for both signed and unsigned ints.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I really understand what you are doing, but I think you got 4 bytes from a stream and know them to represent a float32 value. The way you handling this suggests big-endian byte-order.

Python has the `struct` package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to handle bytestreams.

```
import struct

stream = struct.pack(">f", 2/3.)
len(stream) # 4

reconstructed_float = struct.unpack(">f", stream)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I'm new to Python so I'll need a little time to try it out and understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html?highlight=struct).

Here's a round trip snippet:

```
import struct
sampleValue = 42.13
somebytes = struct.pack('=f', sampleValue)
print(somebytes)
result = struct.unpack('=f', somebytes)
print(result)
```

`result` may be surprising to you. `unpack` returns a tuple. So to get to the value you can do

```
result[0]
```

or modify the result setting line to be

```
result = struct.unpack('=f', some bytes)[0]
```

I personally hate that, so use the following instead

```
result , = struct.unpack('=f', some bytes) # tuple unpacking on assignment
```

The second thing you'll notice is that the value has extra digits of noise. That's because python's native floating point representation is `double`.

*(This is python3 btw, adjust for using old versions of python as appropriate)*

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! I'm new to Python so I'll need a little time to try it out and understand.

Comment: You can accept this answer if you want. It is worth pointing out that the struct module does not know half-precision floating point types.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I think int_list isn't really just a list of ints. The ints are constrained to 0-255 and represent bytes that can be built into a signed integer. You then want to turn that into a float. The trick is to set the sign of the first byte properly and then procede much like you did.

```
float((-(byte_array[0]-127) if byte_array[0]>127 else byte_array[0])*256 + byte_array[1])
```